# Is there a benefit to using FOR SHARE in this PostgreSql simple select?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, locking

In the following PgSql stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_offer_from_id(
        offer_id     bigint)
RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE
    res "entity_data_result";
    r   "get_offer_data";
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM "get_offer_data"
              WHERE "id" = offer_id
              LIMIT 1
              FOR SHARE
        LOOP
            res.found := true;
            res.data := row_to_json(r);
        END LOOP;
    RETURN row_to_json(res);
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

is there a real benefit to using FOR SHARE or can one remove it from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what else happens in the transaction.

With the `for share` there, nobody can update the `select`ed `get_offer_data` row until the transaction commits or rolls back.

Without the context, it's really impossible to say what the original intended purpose of adding the lock there was.

Comment: Let's assume nothing else happens in the transaction. It is just a simple read. I believe I can safely get rid of the FOR SHARE. Am I right?

Comment: @JVerstry Yes, in that case it seems to serve no purpose at all.